# Purpose of AssertRequiredRoles?

Tags: servicestack

I am implementing my own `RequiredRole` attribute called `RequiredAnyRole`, whereby I pass in a list but the user only has to be in 1 of the roles. I have implemented my own method called `HasAnyRole` which simply queries based on `.Any()` instead of `.All()`.

I have then overridden the `Execute` method to use my method rather than `HasAllRoles`. The problem is im not sure what the method: `AssertRequiredRoles` is doing? It doesn't seem to be called?

Should I override that to use `.Any()` rather then `.All()` too? Here is the original code:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/82241fc96e187d12f9db2556aea37cf327813adc/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequiredRoleAttribute.cs

Comment: Nice idea you've in RequiredAnyRole.  How about sending a pull-request to the project, so the RequiredAnyRole can ship with the library?

Comment: I'm currently using your workaround in one of my project.  And it rocks.  

FYI, I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/724) on ServiceStack [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/724) to resolve this challenge (which also applies to RequiredPermissionAttribute) without having to create a separate attribute class.

Please check this issue to voice your opinion on how best to implement this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure, I can submit a pull request. I'd have to do this later though as I don't have access to my repository at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssertRequiredRoles is a static helper method that's can be used by other plugins like [RequestLogsService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Admin/RequestLogsService.cs#L73) to ensure access is only granted to users with the required roles. It's not called when used as a normal attribute filter.

Once you override Execute you retain full control of what gets executed, so you only need to override what you need.